# UITextFieldDelegate stops working after first activation of UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITextField which I made here:

```
text_field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 260, 40)];
text_field.delegate = [[MessageInputDelegate alloc] init];
```

The delegate implementation:

```
@implementation MessageInputDelegate

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *) text_field{
    [the_view5 becomeFirstResponder];
    the_view5->text_area.frame = CGRectMake(20, 320, 280, 40);
    the_view5->message_label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);
    text_field.enabled = NO;
    text_field.text = @"";
    return YES;
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField{
    printf("DID CALL EDIT METHOD\n");
    the_view5->text_area.frame = CGRectMake(20, 140, 280, 40);
    the_view5->message_label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 140);
}

- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString *) string{
    if (textField.text.length >= 400 && range.length == 0){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

It works the first time I activate the text field but not the second time...?

Thankyou.

Comment: Do you create `text_field` in your `MessageInputDelegate`?

Comment: No, the code you see, is the code it is.

Comment: `text_field.enabled = NO` looks like a suspect.

Comment: Yes that was it. I was using that before when activating text fields programmatically and I got confused when I was allowing manual entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used endEditing to close the keyboard and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're cerating `text_field` from yout `MessageInputDelegate`, you should use

```
text_field.delegate = self;
```

and declare delegate for both UITextFields.

---

If yoy create it from other class, you should declare a `MessageInputDelegate` instance somewhere in your `.h` file, e.g

```
MessageInputDelegate *mid;
```

and then

```
text_field.delegate = mid;
```

Comment: Thank you but I retained the delegate in the class I made it and it still fails.